# Java H2 Database - Thread cant access previously committed Data

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, h2

I have a JUnit test that it using an in-memory H2 database as the storage engine. The connection string for the database is:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE
```

As a setup to the unit test, some data is persisted into the database using a shared entity manager (transaction management is provided by Spring).

When a new thread is forked in the test using an executor service, the thread attempts to read the previously persisted data, but returns null, even though it was committed.

Is there anything else I need to configure H2 with to get this to work?

Thanks.